# SQL Server 2017 Setup complete with failure (Client Tools SDK + Client Tools Backwards Combatibility)

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2017

I am new to MSSQL and I tried to install it my local Machine, but above two instance instillation state is failed. I want to know, what are they and how i reinstall that features ?

--------------ERROR LOG----------------------

```
   Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068643839
  Start time:                    2018-03-25 08:55:39
  End time:                      2018-03-25 08:57:11
  Requested action:              Install

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for SDK:             Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.


Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  CWLK-UMAYANGA
  Machine processor count:       8
  OS version:                    Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise (10.0.16299)
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured
  SQL Server 2017      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER            Database Engine Services                 1033                 Developer Edition    14.0.1000.169   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2017      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER            Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search 1033                 Developer Edition    14.0.1000.169   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2017                                                          Client Tools Connectivity                1033                                      14.0.1000.169   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2017                                                          Machine Learning Server (Standalone)                          Developer Edition    14.0.1000.169   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2017                                                          R                                                             Developer Edition    14.0.1000.169   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2017                                                          Python                                                        Developer Edition    14.0.1000.169   No         Yes       

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2017 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2017
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       14
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         E:\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Developer

Product Update Status:
  None discovered.

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  TABULAR
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
  ASTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180325_085539\ConfigurationFile.ini
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
  ENABLERANU:                    false
  ENU:                           true
  EXTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  EXTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  FEATURES:                      SDK
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTPYTHONLICENSETERMS:     false
  IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:      false
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
  ISMASTERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISMASTERSVCPASSWORD:           <empty>
  ISMASTERSVCPORT:               8391
  ISMASTERSVCSSLCERTCN:          <empty>
  ISMASTERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
  ISMASTERSVCTHUMBPRINT:         <empty>
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ISTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
  ISTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  ISWORKERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISWORKERSVCCERT:               <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCMASTER:             <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCPASSWORD:           <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  MRCACHEDIRECTORY:              
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PBDMSSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBDMSSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBENGSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBENGSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBPORTRANGE:                   <empty>
  PBSCALEOUT:                    false
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  ROLE:                          <empty>
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         <empty>
  SECURITYMODE:                  <empty>
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT:         false
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           <empty>
  SQLTELSVCACCT:                 <empty>
  SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:             <empty>
  SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:          0
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT:            0
  SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH:           -1
  SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE:             -1
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH:        -1
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE:          -1
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180325_085539\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Client Tools SDK
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180325_085539\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Comment: Did you look in this file:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180325_085539\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

Comment: @Kevin3NF now ,i checked it,but any thing not fail... bus some component stat in not applicable.

Comment: This might help [SQL Server 2014 installation fails: An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489182/sql-server-2014-installation-fails-an-error-occurred-for-a-dependency-of-the-fe)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem on a Windows 2012 R2 VM wit SQL Server 2017. The solution was to install the .Net 4.7.2 SDK. I don't know if the runtime would be enough but the SDK fixed it for me! While checking the requirements the setup statet that .Net 4.0 ist allready installed but the installation failed!

Hope it help even if my spelling isn't the beest :)